# How to use javascript:location.replace with response.redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

When using javascript:location.replace with Hyperlink.NavigateUrl it works perfectly.

For instance, this works great:

```
HyperLinks.NavigateUrl = "javascript:location.replace('step3.aspx?Time=" + i + "');";
```

This doesn't work at all:

```
Response.Redirect("javascript:location.replace('step3.aspx?Time=" + i + "'); return false;");
```

It appears to just be just posting back to itself or doing nothing.

What's the proper syntax I should be using or, is there an alternative?

Comment: Use a <FORM onsubmit="redirectFunction(); return false", in your context i dunno how you trigger wich event it's from.

Comment: I'm triggering with an asp:button On Click, doing an update to a sql database, sending an email and then redirecting to another page when that's all complete. All in code behind and strictly asp.net.

Comment: if you want to do the same thing post something to update sql and then get an response without any refresh just an update of your data and an select of the result. You need to use ajax to post and got data as response. You ASP.net page need to send header content type with "text/json" and an object Json as return the object from database request ...etc

Comment: Use `Response.Redirect("step3.aspx?Time=" & i)`

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to use the [Response.Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx) method.  A possible syntax for your example is:

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("step3.aspx?Time={0}", i), false);
```

The first parameter of the Redirect method is an absolute or relative URL.

However, the Redirect method will put an entry into the browser's history, and your original JavaScript `location.replace()` method does not.  One way around this, if that is important, would be to use the [Server.Transfer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Server.Transfer(string.Format("step3.aspx?Time={0}", i));
```

But in this case, the URL that the browser shows will not change to "step3.aspx".  You'll have to decide which is the better option for you.